# Web Service Missing In Java Web App WAR File

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, netbeans

I've create java web application and have added web service to it. 
 **Right Click on Project Root Node > New > Web Service.**
Than as I'm using **NetBeans IDE 6.9.1** I found **WAR** file in Project's **dist** folder.
Then copied it to **tomcat webapps** folder. Index.jsp is working properly (writing Hello World in browser), but I couldn't find webservice - 404.  I think that web service is not assembled with my web app.

if that is the problem, **How Can I Assemble Web Service With Web App to A War File?**

[image: java project tree view]

**P.S. When I run project from netbeans with its own glassfish server then webservice is browseable!!!**

Comment: What is in the tomcat logs?

Comment: What do you need from tomcat logs? - I'm new to tomcat and java :)

Comment: Any stacktraces or errors.